Login session not accessible other than redirected page
This is my login.php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username=? AND password=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        $error_message = "Invalid username or password";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

Below is my dashboard.php:
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "Logged in as: " . $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
    echo "You are not logged in.";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="another_page.php">Link to another page</a>
</body>
</html>

And below is my another_page.php:
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "No session found. Please log in first.";
} else {
    echo "Welcome ". $_SESSION['username'];
}
?>

Basically I am logging and after successful login, i am landed to dashboard.php and here on this page, the $_SESSION['username'] is accessible, but when I click the link to another_page.php, then on that page, the session variable is not accessible.
Please let me know where i am wrong.

Never store plain text passwords. Instead use password_hash() and password_verify().

You're checking isset($_SESSION['password']) but you're never setting it to anything, so the condition will always fail. Just remove the second check, you shouldn't be storing password in session anyway.

@AlexHowansky I removed that condition, but now the dashboard.php can access the $_SESSION['username'] but another_page.php cannot access it

You are calling session_start() on the login screen, right?

@ChrisHaas Yes, I am calling session_start() even in login.php, but still issue persists, I think the issue is that session variables are able to propagate from login.php to dashboard.php, but not from dashboard.php to another_page.php

Your issue likely stems from not calling session_start() at the very beginning of your PHP scripts(at least from what you posted), and like Alex Howansky commented, you should use password_hash() and password_verify() when handling passwords.
Here's a slight rewrite with those two things in mind, as well as a few minor improvements:
login.php
<?php
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // set $username and $password like before

  // select `password` instead of `*`
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM admin WHERE username=?");

  if($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

      // usiig `password_verify()`
      if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
        exit();

      } else {
        $error_message = "invalid username or password";

      }
    } else {
      $error_message = "invalid username or password";

    }
    // can't forget this :)
    $stmt->close();

  } else {
    die("failed to prepare statement" . $conn->error);
  }
}
?>

dashboard.php
<?php
session_start();

// specify header location
// moved echo into the HTML
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  header("Location: login.php");
  exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- htmlspecialchars() for security, of course :) -->
    <p>Logged in as: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']); ?></p>
    <a href="another_page.php">Link to another page</a>
</body>
</html>

another_page.php
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  echo "No session found. Please log in first.";
  exit(); // remember to use this, gotta prevent any further execution
} else {
  echo "Welcome ". htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']);
}
?>

additional tip: make sure that there are no outputs before session_start() and header() calls, even a single space can bork session handling and redirection.
edit: You could also use <?= instead of <?php echo, but I don't really like it

I followed your approach, now its not even redirecting me to dashboard.php, because when login.php is executed, i just get blank page, previousy it was redirecting me to dashboard.php, only issue was I was not able to get session variables into another_page.php

The only issue is you are not starting session at start login.php file.
session_start();

